# How to filter and keep only 6 digit number in a dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have dataframe column . I need keep only numbers  which are 6 digits and all others should be named as 'Not Valid'

**Input**

```
data['Post_Code'] 
629785
588778
760-\63
76063
76063
S4P2Z6
NP443HO
999999999
8
4
3
3
460803
460803
460803
760439
569139
ABVCD
```

**Expected Output**

```
data['Cleaned_Post_Code']
629785
588778
Nil
Nil
Nil
Nil
Nil
Nil
Nil
Nil
Nil
Nil
460803
460803
460803
760439
569139
Nil
```

How can this be done.

Comment: "_should be named as 'Not Valid'_" - then why are they called "Nil" in your example?

Comment: Instead of replacing with the string 'Nil', why not use a more universal value like `None` or `NaN`. That'll make it a lot easier afterwards

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) by regex - `^` for start of string, `\d{6}` for `6 digit`s and `$` for end of string:

```
data['Cleaned_Post_Code'] = data['Post_Code'].str.extract('^(\d{6})$', expand=False)
print (data)
    Post_Code Cleaned_Post_Code
0      629785            629785
1      588778            588778
2       760-3               NaN
3       76063               NaN
4       76063               NaN
5      S4P2Z6               NaN
6     NP443HO               NaN
7   999999999               NaN
8           8               NaN
9           4               NaN
10          3               NaN
11          3               NaN
12     460803            460803
13     460803            460803
14     460803            460803
15     760439            760439
16     569139            569139
17      ABVCD               NaN
```

If want replace `NaN`s add [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
data['Cleaned_Post_Code'] = (data['Post_Code'].str.extract('^(\d{6})$', expand=False)
                                              .fillna('Nill'))
print (data)
    Post_Code Cleaned_Post_Code
0      629785            629785
1      588778            588778
2       760-3              Nill
3       76063              Nill
4       76063              Nill
5      S4P2Z6              Nill
6     NP443HO              Nill
7   999999999              Nill
8           8              Nill
9           4              Nill
10          3              Nill
11          3              Nill
12     460803            460803
13     460803            460803
14     460803            460803
15     760439            760439
16     569139            569139
17      ABVCD              Nill
```

Comment: Downvoter, if there's something wrong with this answer, please let this user know so they can fix it.

Comment: @jezrael, Its not working properly, its still keeping 5 digits numbers and all others are filtered

Comment: @Rahulrajan - It seems some problem with data - is possible create better sample with `print(data['Post_Code'].head(20).tolist())` ?

Comment: Output:


['629785', '588778', '76063', '76063', '76063', '651289', '651289', '764502', '169038', '540113', '048622', '682485', '320017', '460803', '460803', '460803', '760439', '569139', '510547', '683684', '228213', '140118', '380018', '389730', '759152', '416352', '127370', '520405', '560208', '538473']

Comment: I test my solution with `data = pd.DataFrame({'Post_Code': ['629785', '588778', '76063', '76063', '76063', '651289', '651289', '764502', '169038', '540113', '048622', '682485', '320017', '460803', '460803', '460803', '760439', '569139', '510547', '683684', '228213', '140118', '380018', '389730', '759152', '416352', '127370', '520405', '560208', '538473'] })` and there are 3 times NaN for rows `2,3,4`. do you get same output?

Comment: Yes same output

Comment: OK, so solution does not work? Are data confidental?

Answer (score -1):

```
data['Cleaned_Post_Code'] = np.where((data['Post_Code'].str.len()==6)\
                                    &(data['Post_Code'].str.isdigit()), 
                                     data['Post_Code'], 'Nil')
```

Comment: Please include a short explanation of your code. You should also encourage the one who asked the question to show an attempt at solving it themselves. There's also a much better answer for this already.